# Is it possible Facebook Messenger Chat app to integrate with third party chat app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, integration, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I want a user to be able to send a message to the chat application on my website from Facebook Messenger Chat, but I can't find an API that I can do so. Is there a Facebook Messenger API that will allow them to be integrated? How do I proceed?

Comment: what kind of chat application that you want to integrate ?

Comment: An application I developed that works on Websocket. Customers add this app's widget to their site and we can start chatting. I want the customer to do this over Facebook Messenger.

Comment: You can not feed input from arbitrary sources into the system so that it appears as if an actual message was send by a user via messenger. At most you can embed the customer chat plugin to get visitors to send their messages to your bot in the first place, and then handle it from there. (But that is likely not going to work for something you want to embed on customer websites, because the customer chat plugin requires quite strict configuration of what domains it can run on.)

Comment: Users of products such as LiveChat can receive messages directly from Facebook Messenger. How do they do that?